# Delete row and restore rowId autoincrement

Tags: android, sql, database, auto-increment

I have a question concerning the deletion of a row in a sql database.
My methods use the id from a onItemClick listener to identify the clicked object but as soon as one item is deleted, these id's don't work anymore because they don't match the id row in the database. Here's an example to clarify what I mean:

ListView in Android

- Item 1 (id 0)
- Item 2 (id 1)
- Item 3 (id 2)

Database (id gets corrected with +1 to match up)

- Item 1 (id 1)
- Item 2 (id 2)
- Item 3 (id 3)

After deletion

ListView

- Item 1 (id 0)
- Item 3 (id 1)

Database

- Item 1 (id 1)
- Item 3 (id 3)

When the Item 3 is clicked now, the entry in the database with the id 2 is chosen but it doesn't exist anymore which causes an exception

I'm looking for a way to restore the databases autoincrementing id column to

- Item 1 (id 1)
- Item 3 (id 2)

Edit: After some research I have to conclude that it is not possible to do that. I'll try to find something like an unique identifier which is stored in a separate table along with the current rowid of the requested object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the id's in your variable object and when you click a listitem, you have to find the object's id and delete it.

Check [this complete tutorial](http://tugrulasik.com/2011/12/21/android-not-defteri-uygulamasi/). using lang translater.

Comment: The deletion works that's not the problem. My problem lies in the database after the deletion.

Comment: Did you refresh the listview after deletion ?

Comment: Yes. It shows all the entries correctly. That's why the ListViews ids are newly assigned (Item 1 = 0 and Item 3 = 1).

Comment: Listview ids automatically sequential, I think that you want to delete item in the database with listview item id, it that right ? So that you have already deleted the data with id=2 and no more data can found. Please import tutorial code, you will find the solution there.

Comment: When an item is deleted all the items after the one that's now missing are not correctly assigned anymore