# rowid of listview item and database doesn't match while deleting item of listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, sqlite

## Here is MainActivity

I use a navigational drawer to populate a listview from a database. When I click the item in listview it starts a new fragment. But when I delete the retrieve note it doesn't match the rowid in the database and the listview.

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);

    mDbHelper.open();
    Log.d(tag, "connection succesfull");

    List<String> arraylist = mDbHelper.getData();

    arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,

    R.layout.drawer_list_item, arraylist);

    list.setAdapter(arrayadapter);


    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```

## NotesdbAdapter

```
 public List<String> getData() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_TITLE};
    Cursor c = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null,
        null);
    String results = "";
    List<String> results1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    int iCM = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TITLE);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        results1.add(c.getString(iCM));

    }
    return results1;

}
```

## Fragment

```
 mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(getActivity());
    mDbHelper.open();

    Log.i(tag, "connection sucessfull in planetfragment");

    Long i = getArguments().getLong(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);

    TextView title = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.title);

    TextView body = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.body);

    Log.i(tag, "click item rowid is :[" + i + "]");

    if (i == 0||i!=0);


    {

        Log.i(tag,"row id after increment:["+i+"]");
        note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(i);
        startManagingCursor(note);
        {

            title.setText(note.getString(note
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));

            body.setText(note.getString(note
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));

        }
    }
    id=i;
    Log.i(tag," id value is :["+id+"]");
    Button deletebutton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.delete_note);
    deletebutton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.item_click, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i(tag,"delete id value is :["+id+"]");
            if (note!=null) {
                note.close();
                note = null;
            }
            if (id!=null) {
                mDbHelper.deleteNote(id);
            }
            getActivity().finish();

        }
    });  

    return rootView;

}

private void startManagingCursor(Cursor note2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public static class LineEditText extends TextView {
    // we need this constructor for LayoutInflater
    public LineEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    private Rect mRect;
    private Paint mPaint;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        int height = getHeight();
        int line_height = getLineHeight();

        int count = height / line_height;

        if (getLineCount() > count)
            count = getLineCount();

        Rect r = mRect;
        Paint paint = mPaint;
        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1,
                    paint);
            baseline += getLineHeight();

            super.onDraw(canvas);
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: `rowid of listview item and database doesn't match` That's pretty **obvious**. Make a custom row in which there is a hidden field where you store the **db** rowId. And use **that** rowId to perform deletions/updates

Comment: i can retrive the click item from listView but i can't delete it because when i see log another item is deleted not not clicked one.

Comment: **Of course**. Re-read my comment.

Comment: how to make custom rowid do you have any tutorial

Comment: Have a look at this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/15832564/2649012. Just make set the "Header" cell `visibility = "GONE"` and use it to store your rowID.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638109/android-sql-delete-row-and-restore-rowid-autoincrement   This is my exxact problem

Comment: OK, so you don't understand the problem. database **ids** `don't change`, while ListView **positions** are always recreated from 0, no gaps

Comment: so how can we slove this problem?

Comment: when we make custom row id. does listview item id doesn;t recreated from 0?

Comment: What you call "ListView row id" **doesn't exist**: it is **not an id**. It's a **position**. So, it's **always** starting from 0. in your database, the row id is a **real**, immutable, **id**. It's like a name. I.e.: The row named "45" is going to be deleted. But the rows named "46" and higher aren't affected. The db ids and the ListView positions aren't paired 1:1. By using a hidden field in a custom row, you will store the db row id at a certain position. So you can retrieve THAT id when you want to delete THAT row. It seems that you have no knowledge of databases, nor programming in general

Comment: i am beginner in android development and slow learner boy that's awesome now i understand thank you for you great help really appreciated!!

Comment: Ok, nobody borns already "learned". ;)

Comment: I put my comments together and tried to make a decent answer, in case someone else has a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

`rowid of listview item and database doesn't match` That's pretty obvious to someone who knows how a relational database works.

Database ids `don't change` (and aren't supposed to), while ListView positions are always recreated from 0, without leaving gaps

Since what you call "ListView row id" **doesn't exist**: it is **not an id**. It's a **position**.
And it's always starting from 0.
In your database, the row id is a real, **immutable**, id.

Imagine it's like a name.
I.e.: The row named "45" is going to be deleted.
But the rows named "46" and higher aren't affected (they don't change their name).

The db ids and the ListView positions **aren't paired 1:1**.

---

By using a hidden field in a custom row, you can store the db row id at a certain position.
So you can retrieve THAT id when you want to delete THAT row.

So, make a custom row in which there is a hidden field where you store the db rowId.
And use that rowId to perform deletions/updates

Have a look at this answer if you need to know how can you make a custom row item for your ListView: stackoverflow.com/a/15832564/2649012:
Just make set the "Header" cell visibility = "GONE" and use it to store your rowID.